# Java Stamp en cierta ubicación de pdf usando iText

Tags: javascript, java, itext

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web usando JS para el front-end y así es como funciona:

1. Inicio la aplicación y abre una página web a través de mi navegador.
2. Muestra una página PDF obtenida de mi directorio.
3. Tengo la opción de hacer clic en un sello y arrastrar y mover el pdf
   y colocarlo donde quiera. Cuando termine, podría hacer clic en
   Guardar y automáticamente guarda el archivo pdf en mi directorio.
4. Puedo abrir el archivo pdf en mi carpeta para ver el PDF actualizado
   junto con el sello agregado.

El problema es que cuando abro el archivo PDF para verlo, el posicionamiento no es idéntico al posicionamiento del sello en el navegador web.

```js
window.dragMoveListener = dragMoveListener;

var heightValue;

interact('.signer-box')
        .draggable({
            onmove: dragMoveListener,
            inertia: true,
            autoScroll: true,
            restrict: {
                elementRect: {top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1}
            }
        })
        .resizable({
            onmove: resizeMoveListener,
            inertia: true,
            edges: {left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true}
        })

function dragMoveListener(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx;
    var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;
    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
    
    var w = $('#pdf-page').width();
    var h = $('#pdf-page').height();
 
    document.getElementById("coorX").value = x  ;
    document.getElementById("coorY").value = y ;
}

function resizeMoveListener(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0);
    var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0);
    x += event.deltaRect.left;
    y += event.deltaRect.top;

    target.style.width = event.rect.width + 'px';
    target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px';
    target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)';
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
    heightValue = event.rect.height;
    document.getElementById("widthValue").value = event.rect.width;
    document.getElementById("heightValue").value = event.rect.height;       
}

function zoom() {
    var $container = $('#pdf-container');
    var lastWidth = $container.outerWidth();
    var lastHeight = $container.outerHeight();
    if (this.id === "zoomIn") {
        $container.outerWidth((lastWidth + 100));
    }
    if (this.id === "zoomOut") {
        $container.outerWidth((lastWidth - 100));
    }
    scaleBoxes($container, lastWidth, lastHeight);
}

function scaleBoxes(container, lastWidth, lastHeight) {
    var $signatureBox = $('.signer-box');
    var x = (parseFloat($signatureBox.attr('data-x')) || 0);
    var y = (parseFloat($signatureBox.attr('data-y')) || 0);

    var parentWidthPercent = container.outerWidth() * 100 / lastWidth;
    var parentHeightPercent = container.outerHeight() * 100 / lastHeight;

    var posX = x * (parentWidthPercent / 100);
    var posY = y * (parentHeightPercent / 100);

    $signatureBox.attr('data-x', posX);
    $signatureBox.attr('data-y', posY);

    $signatureBox.css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + posX + 'px,' + posY + 'px)',
        '-moz-transform': 'translate(' + posX + 'px,' + posY + 'px)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + posX + 'px,' + posY + 'px)',
        '-o-transform': 'translate(' + posX + 'px,' + posY + 'px)',
        'transform': 'translate(' + posX + 'px,' + posY + 'px)'
    });

    var widthBoxPercent = $signatureBox.outerWidth() * parentWidthPercent / 100;
    var heightBoxPercent = $signatureBox.outerHeight() * parentHeightPercent / 100;

    $signatureBox.outerWidth(widthBoxPercent);
    $signatureBox.outerHeight(heightBoxPercent);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#zoomIn').click(zoom);
    $('#zoomOut').click(zoom);

    $('.signer-box').dblclick(function () {
        $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

```css
#pdf-page {
    width: 100%;
}

.signer-box {
    background: url('../images/pen_icon.png') #29e no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: 50%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: .8;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 0.2em 0.2em 0.5em;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none; 
}
  
#signature-pad {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#signatureImg{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   
        <div id="content">
            <div class="wrap">
                   <hr style="border:15px;"><hr style="border:2px;">
                    
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="content">
                            <div id="pdf-container" >                   
                                <div id="signers-list">
                                   <div id="signer-1" class="signer-box"></div>
                                </div>                  
                                <img id="pdf-page" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
                            </div><!-- .\pdf-container -->   
                        </div><!-- .\content -->
                    </div><!-- .\wrapper -->
       
                    <div id="navigator" align="center">
                        <table align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <button name="buttonAction" type="submit" value="3"><<</button>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <button name="buttonAction" class="previous" type="submit" value="2"><</button>
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                            <li>1/1</li>
                            </td>
                            <td align="rigth">
                                <button name="buttonAction" class="next" type="submit" value="1">></button>
                            </td>
                            <td align="rigth">
                                <button name="buttonAction" type="submit" value="4">>></button>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>    
                </table></form>

                    <hr style="border:15px;"><hr style="border:2px;">
                    <div class="content">

                        <table id="customers">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                     X:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="coorX" id="coorX" value="0" readonly="readonly">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                     h:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="heightValue" id="heightValue" value="150" readonly="readonly">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                     Y:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="coorY" id="coorY" value="0" readonly="readonly">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                     w:
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="widthValue" id="widthValue" value="180" readonly="readonly">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <hr>
              </form>
            </div><!-- /.wrap -->
        </div><!-- /.content -->
         
            </div>
            <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.9/interact.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.worker.min.js'></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

A continuación se muestra el código de back-end para manejar la pieza de estampado usando iText:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
    String src = p.getProperty("src");
    String dest = p.getProperty("dest");
    String imgSrc = p.getProperty("stamp");

    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
    ImageData image = ImageDataFactory.create(imgSrc);
    float w = image.getWidth();
    float h = image.getHeight();
       
    float mouseX = Float.valueOf(request.getParameter("coorX"));
    float mouseY = Float.valueOf(request.getParameter("coorY"));
            
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(mouseX,mouseY,w,h);
    PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(rect).setStampName(new PdfName("Approved"));
    PdfFormXObject xObj = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(w,h));
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObj,doc);
    canvas.addImage(image,0,0,false);
    stamp.setNormalAppearance(xObj.getPdfObject());
    stamp.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
    stamp.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.LOCKED);

    for(int i=1;i<=doc.getNumberOfPages();i++){
        doc.getPage(i).addAnnotation(stamp);
    }
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
    p.setProperty("src", dest);
    p.setProperty("dest", src);
    p.store(out, null);
    out.close();
    doc.close();

}
```

Comment: Esta pregunta ha sido reportada automáticamente por el sistema debido a su extensión. No necesitas tomar ninguna medida en el momento, pero lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] e intenta que tus futuras preguntas no sean tan extensas. Un saludo.